# Why does this ZVS Driver circuit use a DC current source to measure the output?

Tags: high-voltage, zvs

I purchased a simple ZVS driver off Amazon to use with a Cockcroft-Walton multiplier I plan on building, but wanted to test the circuit in Multisim first before adding it. The ZVS Driver works well so far, successfully completing an arc across a distance of 5mm between leads. My fluke hv probe is measuring the output at around 11kV. In Multisim, I usually test the output of my power supply circuits with a connector, but after measuring extremely low voltages at output I thought I must be doing something wrong. After looking at other ZVS driver circuits in Multisim I discovered that even though output should be AC (at least with irl multimeter readings...) this circuit seems to only measure the voltage correctly with a DC current source attached to both output terminals. Any thoughts on why this is? Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: With connector]

[image: With DC current source]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must connect the output coil to ground to make the simulator work correctly. There is no ground reference to the HV secondary.

Comment: I added the schematic from the manufacturer to the original comment for reference.